# shared preference null in adapter

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-asynctask, sharedpreferences

This is the view when i click switch rent then async task will run and im getting result an dthe recycle view not updating and it shows image button and recycle view null pointer exception here is my code
[Image here](http://208.77.22.13/proprek_android/img.png)

```
public void rent_buy_selection(String type,String propertyID,String placeId,String buildingName,String bedRooms)
{
    Property_listing1 listing1  = new Property_listing1(type,propertyID,placeId,buildingName,bedRooms);
    listing1.execute();

}


public class Property_listing1 extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Boolean> {
    String PropertyID;
    String placeId;
    String property_type;
    String BuildingName;
    String BedRooms;
    String image1,SenderId;

    JSONArray detail;

    JSONParser ob = new JSONParser();
    JSONArray jArray;
    Property_listing1(String type,String propertyID,String PlaceId,String buildingName,String bedRooms) {
        Log.e("listFragment",":"+type);
        PropertyID   = propertyID;
        placeId      = PlaceId;
        BuildingName = buildingName;
        BedRooms     = bedRooms;
        property_type= type;

      /*  if(getActivity().getIntent().hasExtra("PropertyID")) {
            PropertyID = getActivity().getIntent().getExtras().getString("PropertyID");
        }
        if(getActivity().getIntent().hasExtra("PropertyID")) {
            placeId = getActivity().getIntent().getExtras().getString("placeId");
        }

        property_type     = type;//getActivity().getIntent().getExtras().getString("property_type");

        if(getActivity().getIntent().hasExtra("PropertyID")) {
            BuildingName = getActivity().getIntent().getExtras().getString("BuildingName");
        }
        if(getActivity().getIntent().hasExtra("PropertyID")) {
            BedRooms = getActivity().getIntent().getExtras().getString("BedRooms");
        }
        if(getActivity().getIntent().hasExtra("PropertyID")) {
            SenderId = getActivity().getIntent().getExtras().getString("SenderId");
        }*/

    }
    List<DataProperty> data=new ArrayList<>();


    @Override
    protected Boolean doInBackground(Void... params) {

        try {
            // Building Parameters
            List<NameValuePair> paramss = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();


            paramss.add(new BasicNameValuePair("more_list", "1"));
            paramss.add(new BasicNameValuePair("PropertyID", PropertyID));
            paramss.add(new BasicNameValuePair("property_type", property_type));
            paramss.add(new BasicNameValuePair("BuildingName", BuildingName));
            paramss.add(new BasicNameValuePair("BedRooms", BedRooms));
            paramss.add(new BasicNameValuePair("placeId", placeId));

            try {

               /* if (getActivity().getIntent().hasExtra("shared")) {

                    paramss.add(new BasicNameValuePair("shared", "1"));
                    paramss.add(new BasicNameValuePair("SenderId", SenderId));

                }*/
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            // getting JSON Object
            // Note that create product url accepts POST method
            JSONObject json = ob.makeHttpRequest("http://208.77.22.13/proprek_android/property_listing.php", "POST", paramss);
            Log.d("Parameters",":"+paramss);
            // check logcat for response
            Log.d("Create Response", json.toString());

            // check for success tag
            try {

                String success = json.getString("status");
                Log.d("test123",":"+success);
                if (success.equals("true")) {


                     jArray  = json.getJSONArray("result");

                    // Extract data from json and store into ArrayList as class objects
                    for(int i=0;i<jArray.length();i++){
                        JSONObject json_data     = jArray.getJSONObject(i);
                        DataProperty fishData    = new DataProperty();
                        fishData.Title           = json_data.getString("title");
                        fishData.Id              = json_data.getString("id");
                        fishData.agentId         = json_data.getString("agent_id");
                        fishData.prprtyId        = json_data.getString("property_id");
                        fishData.Price           = json_data.getString("price");
                        fishData.Area            = json_data.getString("area");
                        fishData.agent_name      = json_data.getString("first_name");
                        fishData.agent_pic       = json_data.getString("fb_img");
                        fishData.Bedrooms        = json_data.getString("bedrooms");
                        fishData.Bathrooms       = json_data.getString("bathrooms");
                        fishData.Image           = json_data.getString("agent_logo");
                        fishData.Phone           = json_data.getString("phone");
                        fishData.property_Img    = json_data.getString("image1");
                        fishData.agent_logo      = json_data.getString("agent_logo");
                        fishData.company_name    = json_data.getString("company_name");


                                fishData.shared = "0";
                                fishData.description = "0";
                               // data.add(fishData);

                        }
                        catch (Exception e)
                        {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }

                        Log.e("agent_name",":"+fishData.agent_name);
                        data.add(fishData);

                    }


                } else {
                    // failed to create product
                    // flag = true;
                    throw new InterruptedException("test");
                }
                // Simulate network access.
                //Thread.sleep(2000);

            } catch (InterruptedException e) {

                return false;
            }
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(final Boolean success) {
        String Title="";
        try {


                mAdapter = new PropertyAdapter(getActivity(), data);
                mRVFishPrice.setAdapter(mAdapter);
                mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                mRVFishPrice.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity()));

        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

When click the  rent

```
 public PropertyAdapter(Context context, List<DataProperty> data){

    Log.e("shared",":test");
    SharedPreferences sharedPreferences =   context.getSharedPreferences("reg_id",Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    user_id = sharedPreferences.getString("id","");
    this.context=context;
   // inflater= (LayoutInflater)context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    this.data=data;


    PropertyID        = ((Activity) context).getIntent().getExtras().getString("PropertyID");
    placeId           = ((Activity) context).getIntent().getExtras().getString("placeId");
    property_type     = ((Activity) context).getIntent().getExtras().getString("property_type");
    BuildingName      = ((Activity) context).getIntent().getExtras().getString("BuildingName");
    BedRooms          = ((Activity) context).getIntent().getExtras().getString("BedRooms");
    SenderId          = ((Activity) context).getIntent().getExtras().getString("SenderId");
}
```

How to fix this issue?

Comment: Problem is here             `ImageButton img = (ImageButton)getActivity().findViewById(R.id.imageButton);`. Instead of use `getActivity()` you should initialize `ImageButton` in `onCreateView()`method.

Comment: Remove this _ImageButton img = (ImageButton)getActivity().findViewById(R.id.imageButton);_ from `onPostExecute` and also check that image is not null. This is if `(!img.equals("null")) {` not necessary

Comment: `ImageButton img = (ImageButton)getActivity().findViewById(R.id.imageButton);` you should not access Activity's view from your Fragment. Also getActivity might return null.

Comment: Can you fix this now shared preference getting null @piyush@Vlad Matvienko

Answer (score 0):

This is the view when i click switch rent then async task will run and im getting result an dthe recycle view not updating and it shows image button and recycle view null pointer exception here is my code
[Image here](http://208.77.22.13/proprek_android/img.png)

```
public void rent_buy_selection(String type,String propertyID,String placeId,String buildingName,String bedRooms)
{
    Property_listing1 listing1  = new Property_listing1(type,propertyID,placeId,buildingName,bedRooms);
    listing1.execute();

}


public class Property_listing1 extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Boolean> {
    String PropertyID;
    String placeId;
    String property_type;
    String BuildingName;
    String BedRooms;
    String image1,SenderId;

    JSONArray detail;

    JSONParser ob = new JSONParser();
    JSONArray jArray;
    Property_listing1(String type,String propertyID,String PlaceId,String buildingName,String bedRooms) {
        Log.e("listFragment",":"+type);
        PropertyID   = propertyID;
        placeId      = PlaceId;
        BuildingName = buildingName;
        BedRooms     = bedRooms;
        property_type= type;

      /*  if(getActivity().getIntent().hasExtra("PropertyID")) {
            PropertyID = getActivity().getIntent().getExtras().getString("PropertyID");
        }
        if(getActivity().getIntent().hasExtra("PropertyID")) {
            placeId = getActivity().getIntent().getExtras().getString("placeId");
        }

        property_type     = type;//getActivity().getIntent().getExtras().getString("property_type");

        if(getActivity().getIntent().hasExtra("PropertyID")) {
            BuildingName = getActivity().getIntent().getExtras().getString("BuildingName");
        }
        if(getActivity().getIntent().hasExtra("PropertyID")) {
            BedRooms = getActivity().getIntent().getExtras().getString("BedRooms");
        }
        if(getActivity().getIntent().hasExtra("PropertyID")) {
            SenderId = getActivity().getIntent().getExtras().getString("SenderId");
        }*/

    }
    List<DataProperty> data=new ArrayList<>();


    @Override
    protected Boolean doInBackground(Void... params) {

        try {
            // Building Parameters
            List<NameValuePair> paramss = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();


            paramss.add(new BasicNameValuePair("more_list", "1"));
            paramss.add(new BasicNameValuePair("PropertyID", PropertyID));
            paramss.add(new BasicNameValuePair("property_type", property_type));
            paramss.add(new BasicNameValuePair("BuildingName", BuildingName));
            paramss.add(new BasicNameValuePair("BedRooms", BedRooms));
            paramss.add(new BasicNameValuePair("placeId", placeId));

            try {

               /* if (getActivity().getIntent().hasExtra("shared")) {

                    paramss.add(new BasicNameValuePair("shared", "1"));
                    paramss.add(new BasicNameValuePair("SenderId", SenderId));

                }*/
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            // getting JSON Object
            // Note that create product url accepts POST method
            JSONObject json = ob.makeHttpRequest("http://208.77.22.13/proprek_android/property_listing.php", "POST", paramss);
            Log.d("Parameters",":"+paramss);
            // check logcat for response
            Log.d("Create Response", json.toString());

            // check for success tag
            try {

                String success = json.getString("status");
                Log.d("test123",":"+success);
                if (success.equals("true")) {


                     jArray  = json.getJSONArray("result");

                    // Extract data from json and store into ArrayList as class objects
                    for(int i=0;i<jArray.length();i++){
                        JSONObject json_data     = jArray.getJSONObject(i);
                        DataProperty fishData    = new DataProperty();
                        fishData.Title           = json_data.getString("title");
                        fishData.Id              = json_data.getString("id");
                        fishData.agentId         = json_data.getString("agent_id");
                        fishData.prprtyId        = json_data.getString("property_id");
                        fishData.Price           = json_data.getString("price");
                        fishData.Area            = json_data.getString("area");
                        fishData.agent_name      = json_data.getString("first_name");
                        fishData.agent_pic       = json_data.getString("fb_img");
                        fishData.Bedrooms        = json_data.getString("bedrooms");
                        fishData.Bathrooms       = json_data.getString("bathrooms");
                        fishData.Image           = json_data.getString("agent_logo");
                        fishData.Phone           = json_data.getString("phone");
                        fishData.property_Img    = json_data.getString("image1");
                        fishData.agent_logo      = json_data.getString("agent_logo");
                        fishData.company_name    = json_data.getString("company_name");


                                fishData.shared = "0";
                                fishData.description = "0";
                               // data.add(fishData);

                        }
                        catch (Exception e)
                        {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }

                        Log.e("agent_name",":"+fishData.agent_name);
                        data.add(fishData);

                    }


                } else {
                    // failed to create product
                    // flag = true;
                    throw new InterruptedException("test");
                }
                // Simulate network access.
                //Thread.sleep(2000);

            } catch (InterruptedException e) {

                return false;
            }
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(final Boolean success) {
        String Title="";
        try {


                mAdapter = new PropertyAdapter(getActivity(), data);
                mRVFishPrice.setAdapter(mAdapter);
                mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                mRVFishPrice.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity()));

        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

When click the  rent

```
 public PropertyAdapter(Context context, List<DataProperty> data){

    Log.e("shared",":test");
    SharedPreferences sharedPreferences =   context.getSharedPreferences("reg_id",Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    user_id = sharedPreferences.getString("id","");
    this.context=context;
   // inflater= (LayoutInflater)context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    this.data=data;


    PropertyID        = ((Activity) context).getIntent().getExtras().getString("PropertyID");
    placeId           = ((Activity) context).getIntent().getExtras().getString("placeId");
    property_type     = ((Activity) context).getIntent().getExtras().getString("property_type");
    BuildingName      = ((Activity) context).getIntent().getExtras().getString("BuildingName");
    BedRooms          = ((Activity) context).getIntent().getExtras().getString("BedRooms");
    SenderId          = ((Activity) context).getIntent().getExtras().getString("SenderId");
}
```

How to fix this issue?